# Projecting data after doing a $facet

Tags: mongodb

After doing a $facet I receive this output:

```
[
    {
        "confirmed": [
            {
                "confirmed": 100
            }
        ],
        "denied": [
            {
                "denied": 50
            }
        ],
        "pending": [
            {
                "pending": 20
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

how can I project it into something like this?

```
[
    {
        category: "confirmed", count: 100,
        category: "denied", count: 50,
        category: "pending", count: 20
    }
]
```

I need the faucet part because to extract those numbers I have to do several $match to the same data. Dont know if there is a better option.

Thank you!

Comment: What you ask is not a valid format. This is an object with duplicate keys

Comment: You may want: `[{"confirmed": 100,  "denied": 50, "pending": 20}]` **or** `[{category: "confirmed", count: 100}, {category: "denied", count: 50}, {category: "pending", count: 20}]` which are both valid options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you ask is not a valid format. This is an object with duplicate keys. You may want:

```
[{"confirmed": 100,  "denied": 50, "pending": 20}]
```

or

```
[
  {category: "confirmed", count: 100}, 
  {category: "denied", count: 50}, 
  {category: "pending", count: 20}
]
```

which are both valid options

I guess you want the second option. If you want the generic solution, one option is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {res: {$objectToArray: "$$ROOT"}}},
  {$project: {
      res: {$map: {
          input: "$res",
          in: {category: "$$this.k", count: {$objectToArray: {$first: "$$this.v"}}}
      }}
  }},
  {$project: {
      res: {$map: {
          input: "$res",
          in: {category: "$$this.category", count: {$first: "$$this.count.v"}}
      }}
  }},
  {$unwind: "$res"},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$res"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example - generic](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7XVP_g7Lfd8)

If you want the literal option, just use:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      res: [
        {category: "confirmed", count: {$first: "$confirmed.confirmed"}},
        {category: "denied", count: {$first: "$denied.denied"}},
        {category: "pending", count: {$first: "$pending.pending"}}
      ]
    }
  },
  {$unwind: "$res"},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$res"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example - literal](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nkoKmL8iRqW)